# How to detect if a filename exists (with any extension) in android

Tags: android, file

I want to return true if filename exists regardless its extension.
I am using following method:

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + Images/","filename.*");
if(file.exists())
{
   return true;
}
```

There is a jpg file in this directory, if I search for "filename.jpg", it returns true, but in case of "filename.*" it returns false.

Is there any way to return true if filename is same but with any extension?

Comment: you will have to iterate through all files in that directory, and check their names.

Comment: that is too costly

Comment: any other method!!

Comment: you can try to call some raw linux command to do that, but I think that it will be same way costly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
 File Imagefolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "Images/");
    File[] listOfFiles = Imagefolder.listFiles();

for (File file : listOfFiles)
{
    if (file.isFile())
    {
        String[] filename = file.getName().split("\\.(?=[^\\.]+$)"); //split filename from it's extension
        if(filename[0].equalsIgnoreCase("filename")) 
             // file exists do what ever you want to do

    }
 }
```

Comment: this seems to be only solution right now!!!. but it is too costly as we need to read all file list in directory.

Comment: Ya , and i dont think it will take much time .Give it a go